# Not in a function. Type 'df' to define it here

Tags: radare2

I'm trying to disassemble `main` of programs function in Visual Mode and i want to see Disassembly Graph, but radare2 show me this message:
`Not in a function. Type 'df' to define it here`

*googling result for this message was [radare2 source on GitHub](https://github.com/radare/radare2/blob/master/libr/core/visual.c#L1533).*

My steps:
1 - `r2 program`
2 - `s main` or `s sym.main`
3 - `VV`

p.s.: I'm a n00b in r2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run r2 with `-A` flag or run `aaa` in r2 to analyze all referenced code.
in `r2 -h`: `-A    run 'aaa' command to analyze all referenced code`.

my r2 version: `0.10.6`